# What's the word for the sound of snow sliding down a roof?

Tags: single-word-requests

So I'm trying to describe a scene set in winter, and I've this sentence I can't write to my satisfaction. Basically, I'm at a loss trying to figure out the precise verb that should go into the blank space. The sentence is:

> The lull of the winter night was broken by the intermittent --- of snow sliding down the metal roofs.

I assume you get the picture. I don't have the word for this type of sound. The closest candidates I found are *swish*/*swoosh*, but I've reservations as to their felicity.

Could anyone please supply the appropriate verb for the given context? (Bonus points if some writer of note has used the sought word in a similar setting.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The sound is *whoosh* and the action is *slide*.

> *The lull of the winter night was broken by the intermittent whoosh of snow sliding off the tin roofs.*

From the [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required):

> **whoosh**, *v.*
>
> **2.** *transitive*. To cause to move rapidly with a rushing sound. Also *figurative*. Const. *up*, to enliven.
>
> DERIVATIVES
>
> **whoosh**  *n.* a sound of this nature (also reduplicated); also, an exclamation ‘whoosh!’; a movement accompanied by a rushing sound; a
> gushing or ‘whooshing’ style.

From Billy at [billy.com](https://www.billy.com/blog/metal-roof-homeowners-guide):

> **Is a Metal Roof Right For You?**
>  . . . metal roof owners will be pleased when, as the sun heats the roof up, they hear the whoosh of a
> small avalanche as the snow slides off the house.

I can’t vouch for the notability of these writers, but . . .

> Every noise outside the house distracted her, the whoosh of the snow
> sliding off the roof, the crack of a branch.
>  <sub>[*Christmas In
> Delaney
> Mountain*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-tE8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT14&lpg=PT14&dq=%22whoosh%22+snow+sliding+off+roof&source=bl&ots=gQiO0uhyA3&sig=ACfU3U1ufdV05cfjVsxzVneqOGg34B2lDQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd6oztvIf1AhVqFTQIHUORDUEQ6AF6BAgaEAM#v=onepage&q=%22whoosh%22%20snow%20sliding%20off%20roof&f=false)</sub>

> The truth hit me with a whoosh, a heap of snow sliding off the
> roof.
>  <sub>[*North by Night: A Story of the Underground
> Railroad*](https://books.google.com/books?id=gd6effmGt7IC&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=%22whoosh%22+%22snow+sliding+off+the+roof%22&source=bl&ots=Z4fHPT1peA&sig=ACfU3U0P9IgmN1dwFluDia5hDyvcgMZT8Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0pLSgvof1AhXEFTQIHcyjDGgQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22whoosh%22%20%22snow%20sliding%20off%20the%20roof%22&f=false)</sub>

> . . . a place where at night you will listen to the whoosh of the snow
> sliding off the roof.
>  <sub>[*The
> Mountaineer*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Mountaineer/kH4JAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22whoosh%22+%22snow+sliding+off+the+roof%22&dq=%22whoosh%22+%22snow+sliding+off+the+roof%22&printsec=frontcover)</sub>

More at Google; [search `”whoosh” “snow” “sliding” “roof”`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%80%9Dwhoosh%E2%80%9D+%E2%80%9Dsnow%E2%80%9D+%E2%80%9Dsliding%E2%80%9D+%E2%80%9Droof%E2%80%9D).

Comment: The sound of snow sliding off the roof, as I had said in my comment that was erased. https://ludwig.guru/s/snow+sliding+off+the+roof. No need for whoosh at all.

Comment: @Lambie: The OP asked for "the word for this type of sound" — an onomatopoeia.

Comment: The sound of snow whooshing down/off the roof. The sound of snow sliding off the roof/ Both are too much. The OP doesn't know that. L:ess is better in this kind of writing.

Comment: @user405662 I just gave you two ways to write it in my previous comment.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: @user405662 That is your decision to make. With or without the onomatopoeia.

Answer (score 7):

A Canadian's perspective:  It depends on how you want to convey the image of the quantity of sliding snow.  Having frequently heard the sound (and on occasions been frightened by it - especially in the middle of the night), I like the "the grumble of snow sliding off the roof" (relatively small quantity, slow movement) or, with a thaw in process, "the roar of the accumulated winter's snow being dumped from the roof" (huge quantity, rapid movement, nightmares).

David

Answer (score 5):

**whisper** (n.)

> *Figurative*. A soft rustling sound resembling or suggesting that of a whispering voice. OED

> *Literary* A soft rustling or murmuring sound. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/whisper)

---

> Yet through it all he heard the **whisper of snow seeping beneath
> the doors**, seething along the floor toward his father lying there on
> the concrete, motionless, looking nowhere and breathing nothing.
> [David Wroblewski; *The Story of Edgar Sawtelle*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Story_of_Edgar_Sawtelle/LCC-6fnkzOIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22heard%20the%20%20whisper%20of%20snow%22&pg=PA124&printsec=frontcover)

> Earlier he had glimpsed the evening star through the scudding clouds,
> but now the clouds had thickened and he heard the **whisper of snow
> being driven against the window panes**. [J. Sawyer and G. Devon; *A
> Christmas to Cherish*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Christmas_to_Cherish/rQjdAnmaHuMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22heard%20the%20%20whisper%20of%20snow%22&dq=%22heard%20the%20%20whisper%20of%20snow%22&printsec=frontcover)

> Every time he stopped to breathe, he could hear the **whisper of
> melting snow sliding** down the cliff around him... [Heather Albano;
> *Timebound*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Timebound/p5uSDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=heard%20the%20%20whisper%20of%20snow%20sliding&pg=PT143&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 3):

I propose

> The lull of the winter night was broken by the occasional **slithering** of snow *[racing]* down the tin roofs.

I would leave out *racing*.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/slither)

> **slither**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> **1** Move smoothly over a surface with a twisting or oscillating motion.
> **1.1** Slide or slip unsteadily on a loose or slippery surface.
>
> *we slithered down a snowy mountain track*

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this nice word! :-)

Comment: Related: "the slithy toves" from [*Jabberwocky*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabberwocky)

Comment: To me, 'spasmodic' has negative connotations, as in muscle spasms. 'Slithering' as per the first definition, invokes a twisting motion, like a snake, not the straight line motion of snow sliding.

Comment: @GlenYates the word 'spasmodic' was in the original post, before it was later edited. Also, when snow breaks free, a slab of it often *does* twist and turn on its way down.

Comment: snakes and people slither, not snow.

Comment: _spasmodic_ was a bad choice given the context and therefore edited out. Regarding _slithering_ I've seen this word applied mostly to the writhing movements of a snake or other such reptiles, but maybe one can extend this meaning to apply to inanimate things. You made some really good points ( I read them all before they were removed), @Lambie. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Having no context, I would alter the line as follows:

> The still of the winter night was interrupted only by the occasional
> sound of snow racing down the metal roofs.

Comment: "the occasional sound of snow racing down the metal roofs" suggests that the snow is constantly racing down the metal roof and is occasionally heard, rather than occasionally falling from the roof.

Comment: snow *does not* race off a roof.

Comment: Occasional means the same as intermittent when used here, but I feel like it gives it a more irregular feel than intermittent, which I tend to associate with windshield wipers. They seem regular, which makes me think of snow regularly falling rather than on occasion. If snow doesn't race off a roof, then the original question can't be answered, which is why I altered the line instead of trying to invent a sound for it. The only sound that comes to mind is "whoosh" as the snow falls, but when you add in "metal roofs", it adds another layer. Let the reader interpret the meaning.

Comment: Actually, you're both 100% right, and I'd also like to steal whisper for this one and drop metal completely: *The still of the winter night was interrupted only by the whisper of snow as it tumbled down the roofs.*

Answer (score 3):

*whoosh* is not quite right -- it suggests speed. [Olympic bobsleighs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BT8kMQxQxIw) whoosh. If I were writing your piece, I would use *crump*, which [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crump) defines as "the sound of a muffled explosion".

And "racing down" is also too fast. I would say "sliding down" or "sliding off".

Comment: "crump" as the snow impacts the ground *after* sliding off the edge, right?  I think the question is asking about the sound it makes *as* it slides down the metal roof.

Comment: @Peter Cordes That's right.

Comment: @PeterCordes: You are right. But it's better than _whoosh_.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who lived in the northeast, I would propose **rustling**

> Let not the creaking of shoes nor the rustling of silks betray thy
> poor heart to woman. Keep thy foot out of brothels, thy hand out of
> plackets, thy pen from lenders' books, and defy the foul fiend.
> -*King Lear Act III Scene IV (Page 4), Shakespeare*

Generally rustling applies to lighter objects (that reach a somewhat higher frequency when there is some sort of friction). Thus, depending on the intensity of the snow (viscosity, stickiness, volume, velocity etc.) and what is causing it to slide in the first place.

Alternatives may be **crackling**, **murmuring** as per the aforementioned conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a poetic word, [susurrus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/susurrus) (or susurration) might work. It is often used to indicate a low natural background sound, similar to whispering or murmuring, such as leaves in the wind, water flowing in a stream, etc.

Comment: Don't you think it's too soft a sound to apply to snow sliding off a metal roof?

Comment: @user405662 I guess that depends on how much snow, and how fast it's sliding. I pictured something like this... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frojJUUaiGc

Answer (score -2):

I would go with this suggestion
*"The lull of the winter night was broken by the intermittent whoosh of snow sliding off the tin roofs"*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This word was already given in the accepted answer

Comment: Thank you @Muchina for the suggestion. Not my downvote. :-)